# Oracle 19c :: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I've run below query on 2 different 19c db.

```
select t.table_name, o.* from all_objects o
left join all_tables t
on o.object_name = t.table_name
left join all_tab_columns t
on o.object_name = t.table_name
where object_name = 'DUAL';
```

It runs fine on 19c db with VERSION_FULL as 19.16.0.0.0
whereas it fails on 19c db with VERSION_FULL as 19.18.0.0.0

I do understand that there is inherent problem with query, it is using same alias for 2 different tables. But it works fine on one db & not the other.

My question is whether this change in behavior is due to version upgrade? or could it be something else?

Thanks,
Kailash

Comment: The most likely explanation is more stringent checking of the SQL syntax in the newer version - a bug could have been fixed, or perhaps there's a config option set slightly different that affects the SQL parser. Either way, Oracle Support would simply tell you to *fix* the known problem with the query and call them back if a correctly formed query doesn't work when it should, rather than question why a badly formed query doesn't work.

Comment: See bug 29015273 and [this blog entry](https://mikedietrichde.com/2022/10/27/silent-ora-918-behavior-change-in-ru-19-17-0-and-newer/), which shows a way to revert the behaviour; but you should really fix the query *8-)

Comment: Thanks for finding this blog, Alex.

Answer (score 2):

19.16 has a bug in it that doesn't always catch an ambiguous column reference when you duplicate aliases. But the 19.18 patchset fixed this by correctly throwing an exception requiring us to disambiguate. That's a lot better than Oracle making the choice for us and getting it wrong, with resulting wrong data. So consider this not as a problem, but as an opportunity to fix a bad query.

Comment: Thanks. Fixing bad query is certainly the next logical step. I was curious to know why it fails on 19.18 version and whether it is documented anywhere or not, hence this post.

Comment: I explained why it fails on 19.18. I know about this because we've run into this and investigated it in our company, too. We had several jobs start failing after patching from 19.16 to 19.18

Comment: See the blog entry Alex Pool referenced. Good write up of what I was referring to.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I saw that hence my vote for that comment.